# How to open url programmatically but not open in browser swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl

I need open `url` programmatically when user click to `cell`, but not need segue to `Safari browser`. It is need for statistic on site.

**This is need to imitation like `post request`**

I do:

```
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: url)!)
```

But this open `Safari browser`.

Comment: You must use WebView

Comment: Just use an `URLRequest` to perform this.

Comment: If you want analyze your app, I think you can use Google -Firebase- Analytics, Fabric or write your own web service implementation for this. It's more efficient for your app.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaking, you want to open the URL in the application it self (without navigating to external -Safari- browser). Well, if that's the case, you should use [UIWebView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwebview):

> You can use the UIWebView class to embed web content in your app. To
>   do so, create a UIWebView object, attach it to a window, and send it a
>   request to load web content. You can also use this class to move back
>   and forward in the history of webpages, and you can even set some web
>   content properties programmatically.

**WebViewController:**

I suggest to add a UIWebView into a ViewController (called WebViewController) and present the ViewController when needed; ViewController on storyboard should looks like:

[image]

*DON'T forget to assign a Storyboard ID for it.*

And the ViewController:

```
class WebViewController: UIViewController   {
    @IBOutlet weak private var webVIew: UIWebView!

    var urlString: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        if let unwrappedUrlString = urlString {
            let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: unwrappedUrlString)!)

            webVIew.loadRequest(urlRequest)
        }
    }

    @IBAction private func donePressed(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

Consider that you want present it when the user taps a button in another ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction private func donePressed(_ sender: Any) {
        let stoyrboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        // withIdentifier: the used storyboard ID:
        let webViewController = stoyrboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WebViewController") as! WebViewController
        webViewController.urlString = "https://www.google.com/"

    }
}
```

Or specifically for your case (selecting a cell):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // withIdentifier: the used storyboard ID:
    let webViewController = stoyrboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WebViewController") as! WebViewController
    webViewController.urlString = "URL GOES HERE..."
}
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

if your question really means that you have some data on an external website that you need to access, so that you can extract a piece of information from it, then you probably don't need to display the rendered webpage at all.

You can extract the html content of a page like this

```
    var text = ""

    let url = URL(string: "https://www.bbc.co.uk")
    do
    {
        text = try String(contentsOf: url!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    }
    catch
    {
        print("error \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    if !text.isEmpty
    {
        parseThisPageSomehow(text)
    }
```

How you parse the text depends on what you need to get out of it, but this approach will give you the data you need.

If you use `http` rather than `https`, you will run into the well-documented transport security issue, which will force you to either set up a temporary override for http, or start using https

[Transport security has blocked a cleartext HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http)